# Is pthread_setcancelstate function a cancellation point when enabling cancelability

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Man page of `pthread_cancel` says:

> The cancellation state can be set to PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, in which
>   case all cancellation requests are held pending,

That is clear. 
If there is a pending cancellation request, and `pthread_setcancelstate` call enables cancelability, when the thread is canceled?

1. during the `pthread_setcancelstate` call
2. at the next cancellation point

The default cancellation type (PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED) is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `pthread_setcancelstate` [is not permitted to be a cancellation point](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/pthread_cancel.3.asp) and cancellation is deferred until a cancellation point, the thread cannot be cancelled until the next cancellation point.